# Can I create user on server with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008

How can I create RDP user in server 2008 R2 like this command

```
net user [username] [password] /add
```

I tried to execute this command and response is

> System error 5 has occurred.
>   Access is denied

What are permissions can I give to SQL Server user to do this command from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this from SSMS? SSMS is for interacting with a SQL Server instance, not the underlying OS.

Comment: Off-topic - not related to sql server at all unless you have mis-represented your situation. If you have used  RDP to connect to another machine, the credentials you supplied to RDP determine permissions. It is not relevant that sql server is running on that machines. And note that 2008r2 is completely unsupported.